# Registered WMI providers are failing after upgrade

Tags: c#, installutil

This is a followup question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044720/provider-is-not-capable-of-the-attempted-operation-after-upgrade).

I am developing a c# windows service.

All requests to the service are done using WMI.

I am installing the service using InstallUtils. and then I am registering the WMI schema using [InstalUtils](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> InstallUtils.exe /f assemblyPath.dll

we are getting the path to installUtils using:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory() + "InstallUtil.exe";
```

And in the app.config we are setting:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"></supportedRuntime>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
```

I installed my application on windows 7 and then upgraded the OS to windows 8.
The service is running OK, only that all the "WMI pieces" I have don't work.
I get the error:  **System.Management.ManagementException: Provider is not capable of the attempted operation  for every WMI operation (getInstances, query, invoke method etc.)**

this error also occurs when I install te application on Win8 and then upgrade to 8.1

also the WMI works ok on both Windows 7 and Windows 8 when I am not trying to upgrade.

if I rerun InstallUtils with /f assemplyPath.dll, after upgrade it fixes the issue.
Also if Visual Studio was installed on Win7 before the upgrade the issue is not reproduced.

I thought that maybe the issue is that in Windows 7 the available InstallUtils version is from

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\

While in windows 8 we are using

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

But since I got this issue again when upgrading from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 it doesn't make sence anymore.
but this is just a guess, and I still cannot understand the issue , what this error means? What might be the root cause of this issue?